# Swift cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'String!'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use a piece of sample code from [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/ios8/), about halfway down the page.

```
var inputStream: NSInputStream
var outputStream: NSOutputStream

NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(hostname: "nshipster.com",
                                      port: 5432,
                               inputStream: &inputStream,
                              outputStream: &outputStream)
```

I've placed this in a playground, along with `import Foundation`, and I get this error.

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:6:10: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'String!'
NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(hostname: "nshipster.com",
~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This error is pointing to the first argument, which is clearly of type `String!` and not `Void`.

I changed the code up a bit, to extract the definitions from the method call. Here's the complete playground:

```
import Foundation

var inputStream: NSInputStream
var outputStream: NSOutputStream

let host = "nshipster.com"
let port = 5432
NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(hostname: host,
    port: port,
    inputStream: &inputStream,
    outputStream: &outputStream)
```

Now the error indicates the third argument, presumably happy with the first two.

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:10:18: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'inout NSInputStream'
inputStream: &inputStream,
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't figure out how I can extract `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer` variables for inputStream and outputStream in the same manner, but I think the original sample code should work. Is this a bug in my (and Mattt's) code, or a bug in Swift?

**EDIT**: I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/NSHipster/articles/pull/174) with the corrected code for NSHipster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the short answer is that you need to be passing in optionals instead of non-optionals (to anything that's looking for inout objects)

```
var inputStream:NSInputStream?
var outputStream:NSOutputStream?

NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName("nshipster.com", port: 5432, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
```

That said, it compiles now, but doesn't run because NSStream apparently doesn't have a getStreamsToHostWithName method (at least in the Foundation I get imported)  Never mind this, it's an iOS-only call, so it didn't work with Playground set to OSX.  Seems to be ok with it set to iOS.

Comment: Thanks, changing the types to optionals and removing the extra `hostname:` indicator fixes it. Using the file inspector to set the playground to iOS runs the code (though the socket obviously doesn't connect, since there's nothing running on that port).

Comment: Yeah, in general any inout NSObject you're getting back from CF or Cocoa should be an optional.

Comment: Added quietly in OS X 10.10 and iOS 8.0 `+ (void)getStreamsToHostWithName:(NSString *)hostname port:(NSInteger)port inputStream:(NSInputStream **)inputStream outputStream:(NSOutputStream **)outputStream NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);`